# TooBig: Increasing OSRM # of coordinates

Tags: openstreetmap, open-source-routing-machine

I'm trying to plan out a very specific route using OSRM.  I have 100 coordinates & now I'm running into this error.
`Too many trip coordinates`.  Is there a way to increase the number of coordinates I'm allowed to enter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're running your own instance of OSRM, you can set this in the arguments you pass to `osrm-routed`:

- `--max-viaroute-size`
- `--max-trip-size`
- `--max-table-size`
- `--max-matching-size`

Use `osrm-routed --help` for a full list of options.

If you're using someone else's OSRM server (such as the Project OSRM demo server), however, you're dependent on what options they have set!

Comment: While pretty obvious, I spent 30 minutes failing to grasp it. These relate specifically to the different services OSRM can do. So for map matching increase the --max-matching-size parameter. Increasing --max-trip-size will not help for map matching, no matter how high you go... I went pretty high.